# Right Join vs where a value exists in another table

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization, code-readability

Without realizing it I've switched to the first block of code as a preference. I am curious if it is a best practice or more efficient to use the first block of code over the second or vice versa?

In my opinion the first is more readable and concise since all the columns are from one table.

```
SELECT Column2, Column3, Column4
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 in (SELECT Column1 FROM Table2)
```

vs

```
SELECT A.Column2, A.Column3, A.Column4
FROM Table1 A
RIGHT JOIN Table2 B ON A.Column1 = B.Column1
```

Just hoping for clarification on best practices/efficiency of each statement and if there's an accepted form.

Comment: The two queries are not the same semantics. Right join and semi join are different. Regarding questions on efficiency if they did have the same semantics then efficiency would depend on the quirks of the query optimiser in the product you are using. Which you haven't told us.

Comment: Your first block of code is closer to an INNER JOIN, not a RIGHT JOIN. Even then it assumes Column1 is unique in Table2. My recommendation is not to use JOIN or IN at all, use EXISTS instead, it makes the code easier to read and is optimised for that use case. `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your two queries don't do the same thing.

Your first one

```sql
SELECT Column2, Column3, Column4
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 in (SELECT Column1 FROM Table2)
```

is called a semi-join. It works like an inner join where the resultset has no columns from the second table. This is another way of writing the semi-join, but you have pointed out that your way is easier for you to read and reason about. (I agree.)  Modern query planners satisfy either way of writing the semi-join the same way. This is the other way of writing the semi-join.

```sql
SELECT Table1.Column2, Table1.Column3, Table1.Column4
 FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1
```

Your second query is this. (By the way, RIGHT JOINs are far less common than LEFT JOINs in production code; many people have to stop and think twice when reading a RIGHT JOIN.)

```sql
SELECT A.Column2, A.Column3, A.Column4
FROM Table1 A
RIGHT JOIN Table2 B ON A.Column1 = B.Column1
```

This will produce resultset rows for every row in Table2 whether or not they match rows in Table1. Inner joins only deliver the rows that match the ON condition for both joined tables, and that's what you want.

Left joins produce at least one row for every row in Table1, even if it doesn't match. It's the same *mutatis mutandis* for right joins.